# Java Script to MVC: Controller Variable Passing via Actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

Using: vs'12 Razor asp.net MVC4 Internet App Template EF Code First

- **My `Actionlink` that i am trying to manipulate**

  ```
  @Html.ActionLink("Download", "ShowOpenAcreageSummaryReport", new { controller = "DataToExcel" }, new { id = "AddData" })
  ```
- **The `script` to attempt this**

  ```
  $('#AddData').click(function (e) {

  var optVal = $("#OptionsDrop").val();
  var Xpro = $("#Prospects").val()
  var Xcnty = $("#Countys").val()
  var Xtwn = $("#TownShips").val()
  var Xrng = $("#Ranges").val()
  var Xsct = $("#Sections").val()


      var href = "/DataToExcel/ShowLPRStandardLeaseReport/" + Xpro + Xcnty + Xtwn + Xrng + Xsct;
      this.href = ""; //clears out old href for reuse
      this.href = href; //changes href value to currently slected dropdown value
  ```

  }
- **The `actionResult` to accept these passed values**

  ```
  public ActionResult ShowLPRStandardLeaseReport(string pro, string cnty, string twn, string rng, string sec)
  ```

Now i know this works with 1 variable as i have this code running on another page, however it won't work with multiple.

I have also tried adding `+ "/" +` between the Variables, which had no effect on the outcome.

**How can i change my code to be able to pass all variables??**

Comment: Have you tried with GET parameters such as `some-url/?param1=test&param2=test2` ? Also note that `this` points to the `#AddData` element in the click handler. If you want to change the current location, use `window.location.href = 'someurl';`

Comment: I just now attempted `+ Xpro + "&" + "cnty=" + Xcnty + "&" + "twn=" + Xtwn + "&" + "rng=" + Xrng + "&" + "sec=" + Xsct;` but without the `"?"` let me add this

Comment: OMG ;/ stupid `?` , if you could give a short explanation in your answer why that is required that be great and will be accepted thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with GET parameters such as `some-url/?param1=test&param2=test2` ? Also note that `this` points to the `#AddData` element in the click handler. If you want to change the current location, use `window.location.href = 'someurl';`

The `?` is necessary to indicate the start of the query string parameters.

Also note that you should be encoding the values with `encodeURIComponent` to make sure that you are producing a valid URL.

Comment: Thanks for the added tip : `encodeURIComponent` ill use this from now on